# Is there any log file I can tail for checking when one specific application is opened?

Tags: logs

I'd like to create a script that detects when Firefox is first opened on the system... I thought about using `tail` to tail a log file like the following:

```
tail -f '/path/logfile' | grep -m1 "Firefox"
```

The command `grep -m1` stops the pipe and goes to the next line as soon as the word Firefox appears on `/path/logfile`. For this to be possible I'd have to watch a log file that has this kind of information... The information of the applications that are being opened on the system. Is there such a log file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's not a log file that contains that kind of information.

You can ask your kernel to notify you on `exec`/`execve`/`fexecve`/ `execl, execlp, execle, execv, execvp, execvpe` calls on a specific executable, using eBPF or other debugging tools. You'd need to do the checking for firefox using eBPF, not `grep`. (It feels a bit like you've found a solution to a problem that you don't have :) )

However, you can rather trivially query the currently running programs using `ps`, and since a firefox session probably lasts longer than 2s, checking the output of `ps -A` every second would suffice, and not put any significant load on your system. That you can grep to your heart's delight – I, however, recommend using `pgrep` instead of `ps -A|grep`.

Comment: Ah yeah, I think I've overcomplicated the problem... Checking the output of ps -A works fine for what I'm doing. Thanks!

Comment: as said, it's better to use pgrep than ps -A.